# Spring Boot Cloud: No instances available for api.github.com

Tags: java, spring-cloud, github-api, resttemplate

Im currently working at microservices.

I have this error when i try to call a github API:

```java
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for api.github.com
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:119) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:99) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
```

im using Discovery Server and this is code to call external API

```java
package com.github.ProjectAPI.resources;

import com.github.ProjectAPI.models.GithubProject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Arrays;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/project")
public class GithubSingleProjectResource {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/{projectId}")
    public List<GithubProject> getMovieInfo(@PathVariable("projectId") String projectId)
    {
        GithubProject[] githubProjects = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.github.com/users/XXXX/repos", GithubProject[].class);
        List<GithubProject> projectsList = Arrays.asList(githubProjects);

        return projectsList;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?
When I call URL like localhost all is working fine.

How I make bean:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ProjectApiApplication {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectApiApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Comment: How did you create the `RestTemplate`?

Comment: At another class. It's Bean

Comment: Please show the bean creation above.

Comment: I edit the post.

Comment: You can't use a normal url with a load balanced rest template. See the docs about providing 2 rest template to use

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I changed java dependecy from 11 to 8 and it work.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.github</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProjectAPI</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Downgrading the JDK doesn't really seem like a solution to the issue.